# reading details from bar code

Tags: android, zxing

i am trying to read all information hidden in a bar code , i have implemented the zxing lib in android app , but it is giving me code_128 and all unclear details , i want the exact details , for example if i am scanning a bar code of a book it should give me details of the name of the book and all ..please help where i am going wrong . Is the zxing the right library , i want to develop this app where on scanning all details of the book got  displayed.

Below is the code that i am using to read the details

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
 //retrieve scan result

    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (scanningResult != null) {

        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        scanningResult.toString();
        String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
        formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " +  scanningResult.toString());
        contentTxt.setText("CONTENT: " + scanContent);
  //we have a result
    }else{
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please put the link of the barcode you are trying to scan as it will help understand the issue? Besies zxing is widely used and pretty standard library so it might happen that there is some issue with the barcode itself

Comment: Zebra Crossing is just a library for doing the scanning of 1d/2d barcodes. It won't do all of the legwork of telling you what book you've just scanned!  That's your job as a developer making use of the zebra crossing library!  To find the title and details of the book, you will have to use a commerce API to lookup the details of the product based on the barcode you have scanned!

Comment: You could use an API such as http://www.searchupc.com/default.aspx which you can submit the barcode to and it can return basic product information.  There are many such APIs available, you need to find one which fits your needs

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_128

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number

Barcode is actually a very small String with a special look as strips. I am not sure what/which barcode you are scanning on the book. I will use ISBN as an example, ISBN is a 13 digit code, e.g. `978-3-16-148410-0`, you can get no information simply by looking at this.

> An ISBN is assigned to each edition and variation (except reprintings)
>   of a book. For example, an e-book, a paperback and a hardcover edition
>   of the same book would each have a different ISBN.

However, they are actually unique. Only if you have a library to map the code to the corresponding book, you can get the information you need.

I.e. Without a library, the code gives almost no information.